# For all $x,y\geq 0$ show that $\frac{x^2+y^2}{4}\leq e^{x+y-2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

How do I show that for all $x,y\geq 0$, $\frac{x^2+y^2}{4}\leq e^{x+y-2}$?
Tried using the mean value theorem but couldn't figure out how to use it properly.

Comment: Expand the series of e^(x+y+2) and see that there are positive terms other than x^2+y^2/4

Comment: @user8795 the question is asking for $e^{x+y-2}$, so the series would contain positive and negative terms, so that method does not work directly.